# Read text file and count number of words between two words(Two Dates)

Tags: python, date

I have a text file that contains lot of dates in in it. Dates are of format ( March 4 2012 or March 2012). If suppose I have few words between these dates, I want to count certain word. Like wise, I want to count the same word between each two of those dates and produce an output in exel file with date and count.Can somebbody help me with this?

I've given sample text file.

textfile.txt

BACKGROUND OF THE SOLICITATION
 
At the Company’s 2011 and 2012 annual meetings of shareholders, Biglari previously had nominated individuals for election to the Board. The following is a chronology of events leading up to the proxy solicitation related to the 2013 Annual Meeting:
 
  
*
On November 30, 2012, a telephone conference was held among Sardar Biglari, Chairman and Chief Executive Officer of Biglari Holdings Inc. and Biglari Capital; Sandra B. Cochran, President and Chief Executive Officer of the Company; and James W. Bradford, Chairman of the Board of the Company. Ms. Cochran and Mr. Bradford conveyed to Mr. Biglari the Company’s interest in exploring a buyback of all of the Shares owned by Biglari and its affiliates.  Mr. Biglari subsequently replied that Biglari was not interested in a share repurchase not offered to all other Cracker Barrel shareholders.
 
  
*
On February 13, 2013, during a telephone conference among Mr. Biglari, Ms. Cochran and Mr. Bradford, the Cracker Barrel representatives reiterated the Company’s willingness to explore a repurchase of all of the Shares owned by Biglari and its affiliates.  Mr. Biglari restated his position on this matter and urged the Company instead either to tender for 20% of the outstanding Shares or to issue a one-time special dividend to all shareholders.  Later that same day, Biglari received a written offer from the Company, authorized by the Board, for the buyback of all of the 4,737,794 Shares then owned by Biglari and its affiliates at market price (subject to any adjustments that may be required by applicable Tennessee law).
 
  
*
On February 14, 2013, Mr. Biglari sent a letter to the Cracker Barrel Board stating that he was not interested in a share repurchase that is not offered to all other Cracker Barrel shareholders.  The letter continued that, since Cracker Barrel has the capability of purchasing Biglari’s nearly 20% stake, then worth over $300 million, Mr. Biglari had two recommendations to the Board: (1) tender for 20% of the Company’s outstanding Shares or (2) issue a one-time special dividend of $300 million. Mr. Biglari contended that shareholders deserve a rational capital allocation strategy, one that benefits everyone proportionally.  Mr. Biglari stated that it was his desire to see management succeed because of his investment in the Company. Mr. Biglari concluded that he and Dr. Cooley remained ready to offer their services to work with the Board productively and to discuss ways to augment shareholder value.
 
  
*
On March 6, 2013, Mr. Biglari and Philip L. Cooley, Vice Chairman of the Board of Biglari Holdings Inc., held a telephone conference with Mr. Bradford and Ms. Cochran in which Mr. Biglari proposed that Cracker Barrel pay a one-time special dividend of $15.00 per Share to all shareholders of the Company. Mr. Biglari provided the rationale for the Board’s adjusting the capital structure to return a substantial amount of cash to Cracker Barrel’s shareholders.
 
  
*
On March 25, 2013, Mr. Biglari received a voice message from Mr. Bradford in which Mr. Bradford specified he would place before the Board Mr. Biglari’s $15.00 per Share special dividend proposal.
 
  
*
On May 16, 2013, Messrs. Biglari and Cooley held a telephone conference with Mr. Bradford and Ms. Cochran.  Mr. Biglari inquired about the status of the Board’s review of the proposed special dividend. Mr. Bradford replied that the Board had not met to discuss the matter. Mr. Biglari urged the Company to reach a swift resolution of this matter for the benefit of all shareholders. Mr. Biglari asserted that in the absence of a decision on the special dividend, he would use all means to advance the concept of a special dividend

Comment: you dont need to paste whole text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex to find the dates.

```
import re
regex = '\s(\w+)\s(\d+\,)\s(\d+)' # this will match the form "str int, int"

with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

all_dates = [' '.join(date) for date in re.findall(regex, text)]
```

This will create a list of all the dates in the file, called `all_dates`.

Comment: Thank you for the script. It is working. Can I also include dates of format "Str int"

Comment: That would be another regex: `'\s(\w+)\s(\d+\,)\s`. If you found my answer helpful, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. @hanithdatla

Comment: I have a text file that contains both dates of type "str int" and "str int, int" . Can you help me with listing all dates in an array.

Comment: Try [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with what you have tried.